# Как узнать есть ли строка в строке используя циклы?

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть задача, на вход которой подается строка из слов которые отделены запятыми и слово-ключ. Суть заключается в том чтобы узнать есть ли это слово-ключ в строке используя циклы, ну или же какие-то другие варианты, но запрещено использовать библиотечные функции для работы со строками. Сам цикл ну или же так сказать главный работающий алгоритм программы нужно записать в отдельную функцию. Код прилагаю ниже:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(char str[128], char key[128]);

int main() {
   char str[128], key[128];
   char IsThereOrNot;

   printf("Enter the key-word:");
   gets_s(key, sizeof(key));

   printf("Enter the string, please: ");
   gets_s(str, sizeof(str));


   IsThereOrNot = func(str, key);
   printf("%d", IsThereOrNot);
   return 0;
}

int func(char str[128], char key[128]) {
   int i = 0, n, word = 0, max_word = 0;

   while (str[i] != 0) {
       if (str[i] == ',') {
           i++;
           continue;
       }
       
      
   }
   return ;
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, а в чем Ваш вопрос? Ну, задача есть, код есть - а что Вы хотите спросить?

Comment: Код есть, но он не не до конца рабочий, так как я не понимаю сам алгоритм проверки наличия слова в строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я не понимаю сам алгоритм проверки наличия слова в строке

Я бы написал нечто вроде:

```
// Перебирает слова в строке и возвращает количество совпадений
int func(char str[128], char key[128]) {
   int count=0;
   int rc;
   char *word = str;
   char *next_word = str;
   
   while (*next_word != '\0') {
      next_word = next(word);
      rc = check_eq(word, key);
      if (rc !=0) count++;
      word = next_word;
   }
   
   return count;
}
   
// Выдаёт указатель на первый символ за концом слова
// Концом слова считается пробел или ноль-терминтор строки
// Первый символ НЕ входящий в слово заменяет терминатором '\0'   
char *next(char *cp) {
  
  while ( (*cp != ' ') && (*cp != '\0') cp++;
  
  *cp = '\0';
  cp++;  
}


// Проверяет слова на совпадение
int check_eq(char *word, char *key {
   int l1=0, l2=0, j; 
 
   while (word[l1] != '\0') l1++;
   while (key[l2] != '\0') l2++;
 
   if (l1 != l2) return 0; // Слова должны быть равной длины
   
   for(j=0; j<l1; j++) if (word[j] != key[j]) return 0; // Слова не совпадают  

   return 1; // Слова совпали
}
```

**ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ:** Писал "навскидку" и ни разу не проверял. Только в куачестве идеи.

Comment: Что вы имели ввиду вот в этой части кода? while (*next_word != '\0') {
        next_word = next(word);
        rc = check_eq(word, key);
        if (rc != 0) count++;
        word = next_word;
    }

Comment: Первый цикл while, если что)

Comment: @Иван - "Что вы имели ввиду "

- Именно то, что и и написал в комменте - перебор слов в строке. Если мы дошли до конца строки ('\0') - то завершаем цикл. Функция *next()* должна возвращать указатель на символ, с которого (возможно!!!) начинается следующее слово. Если этот символ - ноль терминатор строки, то работа закончена.